# EF: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'dbo.Currency'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.MwbeCurrency'

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a 2 objects `Purchase` and `Currency` (`Currency` is also a property in `Purchase`).

Now I'm trying to add a new `Purchase` with an existing `Currency` to the database. An error occurs:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Currency'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Currency'. The duplicate key value is `

This happens when I call the method `SaveChanges`.

Generic repository class:

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<TEntity>
{
    public virtual TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        return DbSet.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

Service method for updating payment

```
payment.UserData = userRepository.Get(userId).Data;
payment.Currency = currencyRepo.FindByCode(mwbepaymentmethod.CurrencyCode);

if (payment.Currency == null)
{
    throw new ValidationException(String.Format("NoCurrencyFoundText", mwbepaymentmethod.CurrencyCode));
}

paymentMethodRepository.Add(payment);
paymentMethodRepository.SaveChanges();
```

How to mark that some properties of new object are not new, and they shouldn't be added to database, just reference should be added.

UPDATE 1:
the context is defined as InstancePerRequest via Autofac:

```
 builder.RegisterType<MobileWalletContext>().As<IMwbeDbContext>().InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: Is your currency repo using the same data context as your payment method repo?

Comment: @Paddy: I made UPDATE1 as anwer for you...

Comment: Everything seems to indicate that you have different context instances in your repositories. Do these repositories really receive a context from Autofac?